# Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04 livecd graphics driver problem? I'm using UEFI :P

Tags: 12.04, boot, graphics, uefi, live-cd

Okay, this is my first time asking a question here.  I have used Ubuntu on my computers for a few years now, and I recently bought a Windows 8 (oh no!) ultrabook that I have been trying to put Ubuntu on.  It is a Lenovo P400 Touch if that makes a difference.  Let me get yall' up to speed:  I disable secureboot and fastboot, then successfully installed 13.04 alongside windows 8 with no problems at all.  Both operating systems were fully functional.  Then, after installing a few plugins, I restarted Ubuntu and I received an error saying I was running in low graphics mode, but I couldn't do anything, like, whenever I clicked a button, it did nothing.  I decided, no big deal, I will just re-install Ubuntu but using 12.04 this time (I like the LTS versions more).  BUT..... When I boot to the livecd, it will show the menu to choose what to do, but the menu is tiny, scrambled, and scrunched up at the top of the screen and I can't tell what anything says.  I would like to try nomodeset I guess but I still cant see what I'm doing.  So I decided to reinstall 13.04 because it worked before, but the livecd for that is doing the same thing!!!  So is the 12.04 alternate version!!!!!  I'm really stumped here you guys... is there anyone who could offer any advice?  Remember, I'm using UEFI, not legacy BIOS.  P.S., I checked the settings in the UEFI menu (bios) for any video settings, and I played around with a few things, still nothing.

Comment: I'd try legacy bios if that option is available to you. Also what "plugins" (packages) did you install prior to it falling over?

Comment: I installed compiz-config-settings-manager, VLC, Unity Tweak, heres the bad one:  Grub Customizer :O  I'm pretty sure that screwed up Grub2.  Oh well, I installed 12.04 32-bit in legacy bios over that previous partition, but it wouldn't recognize my Windows 8 since 8 is in UEFI, so that's no good.  I did get 13.04 to load up the livecd, but 12.04 still won't work.  Sorry it took so long to reply, I didn't notice anyone had commented.

Comment: I suppose you now feel the way I do about *anything* that messes with grub: don't. I'm sure there is a deterministic way to get you to a working state, but I don't know what it is and expect it would be long and painful. I'd probably start from scratch if I munged a machine like that. Good luck.

Comment: I have indeed learned my lesson!  Thanks for the input :D

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out a workaround to the problem.  I loaded the boot-menu of the livecd on a friends laptop (using UEFI mode to match mine), I wrote down the options, went back to my laptop, ran the cd, choosing what I assumed were the right choices and voila!  it was only the boot menu that was messed up, the rest of the installation process used the correct graphics driver!